# unexpected end of file

Tags: nginx, https, certbot, odoo

I am trying to get revese proxy working. I followed below

https://github.com/nthnnl/odoo-nginx-reverse-proxy

```
I am getting ginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf:52
```

Here is the sites-enabled file

```
upstream odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

server {
    listen      443 default;
    server_name www.YOURDOMAIN.COM;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/oddo.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/oddo.error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.YOURDOMAIN.COM/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.YOURDOMAIN.COM/privkey.pem;
    keepalive_timeout   60;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://odoo;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.YOURDOMAIN.COM;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Look at all your other configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ssl_ciphers` line is invalid, the line ends with `$`, not with `';` as it should.

The last element before `$` is also incomplete.